# Change a variable reference that is out of scope

Tags: c++

Say I have this code, it compiles. What does `a1` hold after `a2` goes out of scope? Is it still a valid reference to `a2`? Does `a1` occupy memory which is no longer accessible?

```cpp
class A
{
  public:
  void something();
};

void A::something()
{

}

A a1;

int main(void)
{
  {
    A a2;
    a1 = a2;
  }
  a1.something();
}
```

Comment: RAII rules state that a2 is gone now. It may still reside in heap/VM, but that doesn't mean it belongs to you or you can trust that the memory address will be valid. a1 is still valid.

Comment: You might be confusing C++ with some other popular language that uses curly braces and semicolons.

Comment: I generally use C#, where `a1 = a2` statement means `a1` is reference to `a2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `a1 = a2;` *copies* `a2` to `a1` using the *copy assignment operator* of class `A`.

The fact that `a2` goes out of scope does not matter: `a1.something();` is well-defined.

There are no references here.

Answer (score 3):

> What does a1 hold after a2 goes out of scope?

Nothing. It has no members.

> Is it still a valid reference to a2?

No, and it never was. It was a copy of `a2`.

> Does `a1` occupy memory which is no longer accessible?

No. But if it were a `A&` then it'd be a dangling reference.